# Black screen after new hint for Android

Tags: codenameone

I get black screen on Android device if used the new paint hint

`Display.getInstance().setProperty("platformHint.legacyPaint", "false");`

I've tried it on Sample "PropertyCross"

Comment: I experienced that too, I had to switch it back when some of my white texts turned black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed after last server update

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I suggest indicating the device/OS version which would make this more helpful. I think this isn't so much a question as it is a bug report which you should probably file [here](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/).

Comment: reported issue with details